# Can I transfer my TextMate 2 settings to another Mac?

Tags: macos, textmate

I am switching to a new Mac and want to bring my TextMate 2 settings with me from my old Mac. I don't see an obvious way to do this, and searching hasn't brought anything up. Do I really need to re-set everything up again from scratch?

Or is there a way to export/copy TextMate 2 preferences/settings from one computer to another?  Thanks!

Comment: If there is a specific `.ini` file in the `~/.config` folder you can copy from a pc to the other.  `.ini` file contains all the setting of an application.

Comment: @Mattia: thanks, but this is on a Mac.

Comment: Yes, I was referring to a Mac pc!! ;-)

Comment: More precisely, if you are able to find a file called: `texmate.ini` or something like that you can copy it and use again in the other Mac Pc.

Comment: @Mattia, Have you been using a Mac for long?  `.ini`  files are typically used under Windows **not** OS X! Under OS X most normal settings are stored in `.plist` files.

Comment: @user3439894 I did what I suggested once but with an other application. I don't know if this is possible in this particular case. ;-)

Comment: @Mattia, If you're not positive of something then please do not post unveted information as it only serves to confuse rather then to provide valid help.

Comment: @user3439894 I just wrote a comment not an answer!!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've managed to get pretty far on my own, so I'm posting an answer.  If someone else has a better way, I'll be glad to accept their answer.  I ran into some gotchas along the way, so I wanted to share those as well.  Here are the steps I took.

1. Make sure TextMate is not running on your new Mac.
2. On your old Mac, tar up the TextMate and Avian folders under ~/Library/Application Support:

```bsh
$ cd ~/Library/Application\ Support
$ tar cfz TextMate.tgz TextMate
$ tar cfz Avian.tgz Avian
```

(You may or may not have the Avian directory.  If not, skip instructions related to that.)

3. Copy those two tar files to your new Mac and place them under ~/Library/Application Support, and then extract them:

```bsh
$ cp TextMate.tgz ~/Library/Application\ Support
$ cp Avian.tgz ~/Library/Application\ Support
$ cd ~/Library/Application\ Support
$ tar xfz TextMate.tgz
$ tar xfz Avian.tgz
```

4. Copy the TextMate .plist files from ~/Library/Preferences on your old Mac over to the same locations on your new Mac.  For me this was the following two files:

```bsh
$ cd ~/Library/Preferences
$ ls | grep -i textmate
com.macromates.TextMate.preview.LSSharedFileList.plist
com.macromates.TextMate.preview.plist
$
```

5. (Here is the 'gotcha' which took me awhile to figure out.)  You need to *unquarantine* the files you just copied over to your new Mac.  Do this (on your new Mac) by clearing the extended attribute `com.apple.quarantine` as follows:

```bsh
$ cd ~/Library/Application\ Support
$ xattr -r -d com.apple.quarantine Avian
$ xattr -r -d com.apple.quarantine TextMate
$ cd ~/Library/Preferences
$ xattr -d com.apple.quarantine com.macromates.TextMate.*
```

The `-r` and `-d` options to `xattr` say to handle all files in those directories (recursive) and delete the attribute specified.  If you get a bunch of permission errors, place `sudo` in front of the xattr commands.

The above appears to have restored the majority of the TextMate "behaviors" from my old Mac to my new Mac.  I still had to open up the TextMate -> Preferences menu and do a side-by-side comparison, checking and unchecking boxes for various settings that did not transfer over with the above steps.

*Update:*

If you have a .tm_properties file, e.g., `~/.tm_properties`, you'll also want to copy that over to your new Mac.

Comment: Step 5! - Thanks for this. Never would have guessed that was the issue.

Answer (score 1):

TextMate 2, which is still in Beta, places its Preferences Settings in `/Users/$USER/Library/Preferences/com.macromates.TextMate.preview.plist` although I suspect that "*preview*" will be dropped from the filename once it goes gold. Copying this file to a different User/System should, to the proper location, transfer the Preferences Settings.